# Поставте текст перед кругом

Tags: html, css

поставте текст - (Server status:) перед кругом.

[![фото][1]][1]

Comment: Сложно понять, что конкретно вы имеете ввиду

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.status{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -5px;
}

.connect {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: green;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
    margin-left: 94px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

<span class="status">Server status:</span>
<div align="center" class="connect"></div>
```